# TFS 2018 Checkin policy plugin issue with finding notificationEventArgs.NotificationInfo.WorkItemInfo as null when check in from TFS web interface

Tags: plugins, tfs, tfvc

We have a had a TFS checkin policy plugin since TFS 2013 today we are running on TFS 2018 and since the user begin to find out that it is possible to chechin via the TFS web interface we would to also let this be possible when we related a workitem to it. But the problem is that the
notificationEventArgs.NotificationInfo is null when CheckInpolicyEventHandler : ISubscriber event handler hit the ProcessEvent.
Can anyone tell me how to retrieve the workitem information when we check in from the TFS webpage. This normaly Works fine when using Visualstudio or team explore to check in here we have the NotificationInfo with the WorkItemInfo.

Regards

Peter

Answer (score 0):

If you are using client-side check-in policies, then it will only be evaluated client-side.

Server-side plug-ins, which can handle TFS events and either react to them, or – in some cases – even cancel operations. Technically those plug-ins are implementing the [ISubscriber interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/gg235821(v=vs.120)).

You can reference below articles to troubleshoot the issue:

- [TFS Server-side event handlers](http://www.almguide.com/2011/12/tfs-server-side-event-handlers/)
- [Team Foundation Server 2010 Event Handling with Subscribers](http://Team%20Foundation%20Server%202010%20Event%20Handling%20with%20Subscribers)
- [TfsPlugin2013 - Sample](https://github.com/softsan/TfsPlugin2013)